# C++17 and template argument deduction for smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++17, unique-ptr, template-argument-deduction

I am playing around with Clang++ 9.0 and it seems that `unique_ptr` can not deduce `<Image>` from the constructor argument type `Image*`:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class Image {
    std::vector<char> data_;
public:
    explicit Image(const std::string& filename) { /*load...*/ }
    void draw() const { /*...*/ };
};
// This is "old" style:
std::unique_ptr<Image> image1 { new Image{"MonaLisa.jpg"} };
// This would be template argument deduction:
std::unique_ptr image2 { new Image{"DerSchrei.jpg"} };  // ERROR
```

There seem to be the hints missing that allow the deduction from `Image*` to `Image`.

This could be an oversight in the spec, or it could be a bug in Clang's STL or or could be by design. What is it? If it is by design, what is the reason?